# How to catch error or fire callback when creating direct line connection BotFramework-WebChat

Tags: direct-line-botframework

I'm using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) to create a direct line connection to my bot from a web page and I want to have the chat pop up when the conversation has started.

I have some variation of this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now I'm getting an error when the bot tries to connect and I want to catch that and not show the chat box.

Is there a way i can have a callback fire when either the conversation connects succssfully or there is an error?